# Ho to plot a cartopy map for every column?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
     CODE   LONGITUDE  LATITUDE     JAN     FEB     MAR
0    000130 -80.50546  -3.81190  105.98  197.22  168.50
1    000132 -80.39504  -3.50380   59.15  131.43  107.35
2    000134 -80.23324  -3.56732  120.74  191.54  146.08
3    000135 -80.28020  -3.45171   65.51  144.87  141.16
4    000136 -80.65058  -3.93910   90.23  162.96  161.81
..      ...       ...       ...     ...     ...     ...
369  158327 -69.81306 -17.23722  104.88   92.62   77.26
370  158328 -69.77944 -17.52500  105.39   98.35   74.97
395  000860 -69.64361 -17.30500  124.40  101.90   81.60
436  157311 -72.33861 -15.26056  105.10  109.30   87.10
471  000790 -69.15686 -15.21667  248.60  198.70  184.70
```

I want to plot a map for every month column (month columns are JAN, FEB, MAR, ... etc.)

I was thinking in groupby the dataframe by month columns like this:
But i get an error message.

Also i don't know how to get the `values`

```
for data in pp.groupby['ENE','FEB','MAR','ABR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AGO','SEP','OCT','NOV','DIC']:
    
    lons, lats= np.array(data['LONGITUDE']), np.array(data['LATITUDE'])
    values=np.array(data).astype(int)
    
    fig = plt.figure('map', figsize=(7,7), dpi=200)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.80, 0.75], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    plt.title('month column {month}')
    plt.xlabel('LONGITUDE') 
    plt.ylabel('LATITUDE') 
    
    ax.outline_patch.set_linewidth(0.3)
    
    l = NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries', scale='50m', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(l, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)
    
    img = ax.scatter(lons, lats, s=7, c=values, cmap='viridis',
                     marker='o', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    cb = plt.colorbar(img, extend='both',
                        spacing='proportional', orientation='horizontal',
                        cax=fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.07, 0.76, 0.02]))
    
    ax.set_extent([-83.0, -60.0, -19.0, 1.0], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
    ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8)
    ax.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black')
    
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
   
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig("path/to/save/fig/.png")
```

Would you mind to help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code generally working, though you may still have to solve a couple of formatting issues as well as keep in mind for later the deprecation warning associated with [`outline_patch`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.outline_patch).

I ran the this code with just the first five rows of your dataframe.  Notice that I commented out the line relating to `COUNTIES` data because I did not have access.

Since the `c` argument of `ax.scatter()` requires values between 0 and 1, I scaled the values for each month by the max of that month.  This means month-to-month variation between maps may not be obvious unless you choose some other way of scaling `values`, perhaps on the whole array of month values instead.

```
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

for month in ['JAN','FEB','MAR']:
    
    data = df[['CODE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE', month]]
    
    lons, lats= np.array(data['LONGITUDE']), np.array(data['LATITUDE'])
    values=np.array(data[month]).astype(float)
    
    fig = plt.figure('map', figsize=(7,7), dpi=200)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.80, 0.75], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    plt.title(f'month column {month}')
    plt.xlabel('LONGITUDE') 
    plt.ylabel('LATITUDE') 
    
    ax.outline_patch.set_linewidth(0.3)
    
    l = NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries', scale='50m', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(l, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)
    
    img = ax.scatter(lons, lats, s=7, c=values/max(values), cmap='viridis',
                     marker='o', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    cb = plt.colorbar(img, extend='both',
                        spacing='proportional', orientation='horizontal',
                        cax=fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.07, 0.76, 0.02]))
    
    ax.set_extent([-83.0, -60.0, -19.0, 1.0], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
    ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8)
    # ax.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black')
    
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
   
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig(f"path/to/save/fig/{month}.png")
```

The first plot it generated was:

[image]